# SCRIPT1014: Find Invalid character in IE8 and IE9

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using image upload functionality without refresh page.

I have a ajax file fileUploadAjax.php

```
$res['res'] =   '<img src="'.frontpath(CLASSES_DIRECTORY.FILENAME_TIMTHUMB.'?src='.frontpath(UPLOADS_DIRECTORY.WHOAREYOU_DIRECTORY.$imageName).'&h=150&w=150&zc=1').'" alt="'.$userDetailsOb->getUserName($uId).'" title="'.$userDetailsOb->getUserName($uId).'" />';

echo json_encode($res);
```

Second file is whoAreYou.php, I am trying to get response using

```
var imagPathWithImageTag    =   jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

but jQuery.parseJSON(data); is not working in IE9 and IE8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use simple

```
var imagPathWithImageTag    =   data.res;
```

**UPDATE** 
your json is not correct

```
 {"res":"<img title='\"Revin' alt='\"Revin' src='\"http:\/\/192.168.2.30\/services\/classes\/timthumb.php?src=http:\/\/192.1‌​68.2.30\/services\/uploads\/whoAreYou\/20140413073613batista-2052979.jpg&amp;h=15‌​0&amp;w=150&amp;zc=1\"' \="" Revinfotech\?="">"}

`\='\" Revinfotech\?=""` this is not well formatted
```

when you formatted this part  it works 
i tried to remove this part then it works

Comment: see in console that what is coming in data

Comment: your method is giving undefined value and my is giving  {"res":"<img title='\"Revin' alt='\"Revin' src='\"http:\/\/192.168.2.30\/services\/classes\/timthumb.php?src=http:\/\/192.168.2.30\/services\/uploads\/whoAreYou\/20140413073613batista-2052979.jpg&amp;h=150&amp;w=150&amp;zc=1\"' \="" Revinfotech\?="">"}

Comment: and you doing your work on ajax success or out side of ajax success